# How to accept date only in yyyy-MM-dd format in ASP.NET WEB API from Form body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

```
public void Post([FromBody]DateTime value)
{
    // do something
}
```

value should be always in yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: what does it even mean? You're getting DateTime, which has no format at all, it's not a string represantation of date, it's an actual date.

Comment: I need to validate in a yyyy-MM-dd format that matters for me

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you want to validate more than just the fact that the type matches but that the data passed in as a primitive from the body of the request matches some desired format that validation must be done in the action method if it is not done at the client level. This is one attempt that I came up with that seemed to provide the desired behavior.

```
 @{
Layout = null;
 }

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/question2ClientController.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div>
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
   <input id="mydate" type="text" size="10" />
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

contents on the question3bclientcontroller.js file

```
 var request = function (event) {
var ajaxOptions = {};
ajaxOptions.url = "/api/question3api";
ajaxOptions.type = "POST";
ajaxOptions.data = {'' : '' + event.data.val()};
ajaxOptions.success = function (result) {
    console.log(result);
};
ajaxOptions.error = function (jqXHR) {
    console.log("found error");
    console.log(jqXHR);
};
$.ajax(ajaxOptions);
 }

 $(function () {
var date = $("#mydate");
$('#submit').click(date, request);
 })
```

Api Controller Action Method

```
 public IHttpActionResult PostDate([FromBody]string dateString)
    {
        try
        {
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return Ok(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest("Unable to parse value in post to DateTimeString");
        }
    }
```